# Installing Octave on raspberry pi

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, octave

I'm using Linux Debian on Raspberry PI and have installed Octave. Here is Octave startup :

```
pi@pi1 ~ $ octave
octave: X11 DISPLAY environment variable not set
octave: disabling GUI features
GNU Octave, version 4.0.0
Copyright (C) 2015 John W. Eaton and others.
This is free software; see the source code for copying conditions.
There is ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or
FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  For details, type 'warranty'.

Octave was configured for "arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf".

Additional information about Octave is available at http://www.octave.org.

Please contribute if you find this software useful.
For more information, visit http://www.octave.org/get-involved.html

Read http://www.octave.org/bugs.html to learn how to submit bug reports.
For information about changes from previous versions, type 'news'.
```

When attempt to run Octave GUI such as :

plot(3,3) the output is displayed on command line :

[image]

Message "octave: disabling GUI features" (as part of startup output above) indicates cannot use GUI features. 
What version of Linux should I install on PI and version of Octave in order to GUI plot such as :

[image]

Comment: Maybe `export DISPLAY=0:0` or something like that? (supposing you have an Xserver running somewhere)

Comment: @wildplasser xserver appears to be some kind of screen server ? If  install xserver on Pi Octave is running plots should then display ?

Comment: I don't know if X11 runs on a pi. Dont know either if it is installed by default. It might. If you are accessong the pi via a remote machine you could use the display on the machine where your terminal/keyboard/monitor is. This needs xallow on the terminal-host + an environment var DISPLAY=... on the pi.

Comment: Correction: it is not called xallow, but xhost. (ssh/telnet have an option for setting DISPLAY=... on the targer(pi) too, IIRC)

Answer (score 0):

As I can guess from your first screenshot, you are using putty from a windows machine to ssh into your raspberry pi. You have to enable X11 forwarding in Putty (Connections->SSH->X11) and install a X11 server on the windows side like Xming (http://sourceforge.net/projects/xming/). Or the easiest way: Plug a monitor to your RaspberryPI and use GNU/Linux and Octave directly.

Answer (score 0):

Connect a screen and execute command

> startx

to start X server, then open a terminal and try installing from the terminal. If you don't have a screen then do X11 forwarding as mentioned by @Andy.